# Change histogram color with plot.pheno function in R studio?

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I've produced a histogram using the [plot.pheno](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/qtl/versions/1.20-15/topics/plot.pheno) function from the R/QTL package. I cannot get the bars' fill color to change though. I've pasted below the codes that I've tried, but they haven't worked. Has anyone got any ideas how to get the bar colors to change within the plot.pheno function? For reference, the bar colors are white by default.

```
plot.pheno(myData, pheno.col = 8, xlab = "My Y Label", ylab = "My X Label", xlim=c(79,123), ylim=c(0,45), breaks = seq(76, 124, by = 4), col = "black")

plot.pheno(myData, pheno.col = 8, xlab = "My Y Label", ylab = "My X Label", xlim=c(79,123), ylim=c(0,45), breaks = seq(76, 124, by = 4), col = black)

plot.pheno(myData, pheno.col = 8, xlab = "My Y Label", ylab = "My X Label", xlim=c(79,123), ylim=c(0,45), breaks = seq(76, 124, by = 4), col = I("black"))

#This one gives the error: "color is not a graphical parameter"
plot.pheno(myData, pheno.col = 8, xlab = "My Y Label", ylab = "My X Label", xlim=c(79,123), ylim=c(0,45), breaks = seq(76, 124, by = 4), color="black")
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example, for instance paste the output of `dput(myData)` or a subset, so we can run your code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a bug in the code of `plot.pheno`, or the authors didn't think the functionality worth including, as the fill colour is hard coded to white.

Though that sounds like a bummer, the good thing is that this is open source, and `plot.pheno` is written in plain R, so it's easy to edit the function and save it to a new name.

```
library(qtl); data(fake.bc)

plot.pheno2 <- plot.pheno
body(plot.pheno2)[[10]][[3]][[2]][[4]] <- NULL
environment(plot.pheno2) <- asNamespace("qtl")

plot.pheno2(fake.bc, col="black")
```

[image]

What's happening in `body(plot.pheno2)[[10]][[3]][[2]][[4]] <- NULL` is that the element `, col = "white"` is simply removed. This can be done more manually by:

```
plot.pheno2 <- edit(plot.pheno)
# edit out ', col = "white"', save and close the window
environment(plot.pheno2) <- asNamespace("qtl")
```